# Simple Java OOP Class Error

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm trying to print my name using Java OOP Classes, Objects and Method. Below are the two scripts I'm using. Nothing is showing on the screen. I'm using Netbeans IDE.

```
package name;
public class Begin {
    public static void displayName(){
        System.out.print("Say My Name");
    }
}
```

===========================

```
package usename;
 import name.Begin;
public Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.print**ln** : "print-line". And an import name.Begin is missing.

Comment: @JoopEggen: `System.out.print()` is a valid method. The difference being it doesn't print a newline character at the end.

Comment: I've tried to answer your question below. If the answers given do not solve all your problems, please also post what error messages you get when you compile this code.

Comment: How are you running this program? Without `import name.Begin` in the Useaname class it shouldn't even compile...

Comment: @kidtempo I updated my question. I'm not getting any error, but not showing the print statement.

Comment: @tskuzzy: sorry I thought `System.out.print` still does not flush the text to the screen, till a `System.out.println` or `flush` is done. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `class` in your "Useaname" class declaration.

```
public class Useaname {
```

Comment: +1 for nice catch :) this is the only issue in the code. nothing to do with static and all

Answer (score 2):

Where is Your Keyword `class` before your Username  ?? :)

```
public class Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the method `static` in order to call it like `Begin.displayName()`.

```
public static void displayName() {
```

This tells makes the method a function of the class as opposed to any particular instance of the class.

Alternatively, you can instantiate an object to call the method:

```
Begin begin = new Begin();
begin.displayName();
```

Comment: Thanks I added static to the method and still does not display the method.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the keyword `class` before the class name `Useaname`. Here is the solution code.

```
package usename;

import name.Begin;

public class Useaname {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should not compile.

`Begin.displayName();` tries to invoke static method - you dont have such a thing :).

you have to ways - create new `Begin` object and invoke method on it - `new Begin().displayName()`

or declare `displayName` as static method.

Comment: Thanks I added static to the method and still does not display the method.

Comment: @Kanyinsola Oyesanmi Does code compile? I'm pretty sure you need import declaration, to run that program....

Comment: @Kanyinsola What happens when you compile the program? Do you get any error messages? If so, please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions to this problem:

(1) You can make the `displayName()` method static. This will allow you to call it with the class name.

```
public static void displayName() { 
  // snip
}
```

(2) You can create an object from your `Begin` class in order to call the non-static member method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Begin b = new Begin();

  b.displayName();  
}
```

To summarize, you should learn about objects and object creation as a beginning step to understanding Java and OOP in general.

Comment: Thanks I added static to the method and still does not display the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static modifier on your displayName() method or create a new instance of your Begin class:

```
package usename;

public class Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Begin begin = new Begin();
       begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I added static to the method and still does not display the method.

Comment: Make sure your `Useaname` class is defined with the word `class` (see my example above) so that Java knows how to deal with it. Also make sure that your package name is correct I see that your class is called UseAname and your package is usename without an A in the middle...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't use the keyword "class" before "usename"

```
package usename;
 import name.Begin;
public Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

**Correction**

```
package usename;
 import name.Begin;
public class Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `class` keyword ! and you can create object for class `Begin`

```
 import name.Begin;
public class Usaname
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
          Begin ob = new Begin();
          ob.displayName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add **class** before Username

```
package username;
import name.Begin;
public class username{
      public static void main(String[] args){
            Begin.displayName();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is the `class` keyword before Username class declaration

Since you declared the `displayName()` method as static using the `static` access modifier , there is no need to create an object of the `Begin` class in order to invoke the `displayName()` method.

In general , this is how the `Username` class should be :

```
package usename;
import name.Begin;
public class Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Begin.displayName();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can invoke the `displayName()` using a class instance by creating an object of the `Begin` class, just like this:

```
package usename;
import name.Begin;
public Useaname {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Begin b = new Begin();
       b.displayName();
    }
}
```